# How to find the interface i.e. the set of provided function of an OCaml package?

Tags: ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, opam, ppx

I need to use parse an OCaml source file into a typed AST and I believe ppx_jane is the right package to do the work. After installing it using opam, I still don't know what functions are available.

This is a [link](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ppx_jane/ppx_jane.113.24.01/) to the ppx_jane package on opam. It tells no more than the basic info and dependencies.

Though I could search on Github to see how other programmers call functions provided by this package, I still cannot get an exhaustive list of all available functions.

Comment: Doesn't this page : https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_driver help you ?

Comment: Could you give more information about what you want to do exactly ? Because ppx_jane is not at all what you need to turn OCaml source files into an AST (typed or not). ppx_jane is just a bundle of all the syntax extensions used by janestreet.

Comment: I originally intended to use ppx_ast by jane street. However, there is a problem with its jbuild (I have submitted an issue). So I am looking for package that may contain a function that can convert a piece of OCaml code to a type AST.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this type AST? The answer to your question will depend on what is your actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for your original problem, (OCaml source file -> typed AST ) doesn't `ocamlc -dtypedtree a.ml` do the job?

About knowing the set of function provided by an OCaml module there are several options. Here's few of them:

1. looking at the doc online
2. in your favorite toplevel :

   ```
   #require "package_name";;
   #show Module_name;;
   ```
3. `ocamlc -i module.ml`

Comment: Options 2 and 3 are not really working for ppx documentation.